# Unwrap python nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, networkx

I have a nested dictionary of this sequence:

```
data_dict = {0: [{1: 2}, {2: 3}, {3: 6}, {7: 8}], 1: [{0: 2}, {4: 7}, {2: 5}], 2: [{0: 3}, {1: 5}, {5: 4}, {11: 5}], 
3: [{0: 6}, {6: 2}, {11: 4}], 4: [{1: 7}], 5: [{2: 4}, {8: 3}], 6: [{3: 2}, {9: 3}], 7: [{0: 8}], 8: [{5: 3}], 9: [{6: 3}, {10: 6}], 
10: [{9: 6}], 11: [{2: 5}, {3: 4}]}
```

I want to unwrap the dictionaries to a list:

```
0   1  2
0   2  3
0   3  6
0   7  8
1   4  7
1   2  5
2   5  4
2  11  5
3   6  2
3  11  4
5   8  3
6   9  3
9  10  6
```

Precisely, I want to create a `networkX` graph from the nested dictionary. Any help please.

Comment: The question is not clear, particularly the last part. What is 'my algorithm'? Where did `adj_list` come from? Why is it the same shape as `graph` but contains different data? What are the inner dictionary values, are they edge weights?

Comment: Also there's no point in representing a pair of values as a single-element dictionary. Use a tuple with 2 elements.

Comment: In your final list, which ones are your nodes?

Answer (score 0):

### Nested `dict`

```
{0: [{1: 2}, {2: 3}, {3: 6}, {7: 8}],
 1: [{0: 2}, {4: 7}, {2: 5}],
 2: [{0: 3}, {1: 5}, {5: 4}, {11: 5}],
 3: [{0: 6}, {6: 2}, {11: 4}],
 4: [{1: 7}],
 5: [{2: 4}, {8: 3}],
 6: [{3: 2}, {9: 3}],
 7: [{0: 8}],
 8: [{5: 3}],
 9: [{6: 3}, {10: 6}],
 10: [{9: 6}],
 11: [{2: 5}, {3: 4}]}
```

### unwrap

```
results = []
for v,list_dicts in data_dict.items():
    for d in list_dicts:
        results.append([v,list(d.keys())[0],list(d.values())[0]])
results
```

[out]

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 6],
 [0, 7, 8],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [1, 4, 7],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [2, 0, 3],
 [2, 1, 5],
 [2, 5, 4],
 [2, 11, 5],
 [3, 0, 6],
 [3, 6, 2],
 [3, 11, 4],
 [4, 1, 7],
 [5, 2, 4],
 [5, 8, 3],
 [6, 3, 2],
 [6, 9, 3],
 [7, 0, 8],
 [8, 5, 3],
 [9, 6, 3],
 [9, 10, 6],
 [10, 9, 6],
 [11, 2, 5],
 [11, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using itertools and comprehensions. (I admit it's probably not the easiest to read at first sight though.)

It also handles having more than one pair per dict.

If you prefer to have the pair as a tuple within the output, remove the unpacking `*` in `*pair`.

```
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint

data_dict = {
    0: [{1: 2}, {2: 3}, {3: 6}, {7: 8}],
    1: [{0: 2}, {4: 7}, {2: 5}],
    2: [{0: 3}, {1: 5}, {5: 4}, {11: 5}],
    3: [{0: 6}, {6: 2}, {11: 4}],
    4: [{1: 7}],
    5: [{2: 4}, {8: 3}],
    6: [{3: 2}, {9: 3}],
    7: [{0: 8}],
    8: [{5: 3}],
    9: [{6: 3}, {10: 6}],
    10: [{9: 6}],
    11: [{2: 5}, {3: 4}],
}

data_list = list(chain(*(
    [(key, *pair) for pair in chain(*(d.items() for d in dicts))]
    for (key, dicts)
    in data_dict.items()
)))

pprint(data_list)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 3, 6),
 (0, 7, 8),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 4, 7),
 (1, 2, 5),
 (2, 0, 3),
 (2, 1, 5),
 (2, 5, 4),
 (2, 11, 5),
 (3, 0, 6),
 (3, 6, 2),
 (3, 11, 4),
 (4, 1, 7),
 (5, 2, 4),
 (5, 8, 3),
 (6, 3, 2),
 (6, 9, 3),
 (7, 0, 8),
 (8, 5, 3),
 (9, 6, 3),
 (9, 10, 6),
 (10, 9, 6),
 (11, 2, 5),
 (11, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    ls = []
rows = 0
for key in data_dict:
    for tempValue in data_dict[key]:
        # print(tempValue)
        ls.append([])
        for (k, v) in tempValue.items():
            ls[rows].append(key)
            ls[rows].append(k)
            ls[rows].append(v)
        rows+=1
print(ls)
```

this should solve your problem